# DBNull -Conversion Error

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am having below error

Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid. When submit the form above error is showing Is it because of any fields in database having NULL VALUE or what could be the real reason.

When I click save

```
              Dim intresult As String
              Dim objParam As OleDbParameter() = {objDA.OutputParam("@Next_DocumentNo",     OleDbType.VarChar, 20), _
                objDA.InputParam("@Dtype", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, "D"), _
                objDA.InputParam("@MID", OleDbType.VarChar, 20, Session("Mid"))}

    intresult = objDA.ExecSP("dbo.GetNextDocNo", objParam)

    If intresult = 1 Then
        tNextDocNo = objDA.varOutputRet
    Else
                    Exit Sub
    End If
    vDocType = "D"

    vAllocID = "501"
    vDummy = " "
    vDummyBuyer = "NEX"
    vRemarks = Replace(Replace(Me.TextRemark.Text, "'", "''"), vbCrLf, "")

      strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.Hder (Document_Type, Document_No, Document_Date, Trans_Type, Type_Desc, V_Type, " & _
        "Mid,Total_Amount, Total_Qty,Prepared_By,Remarks) " & _
         "VALUES ('" & vDocType & "', '" & tNextDocNo & "', '" & Me.TextDate.Text & "', 'D', 'gift IN', 'GIFT',  " & _
        "'" & Mid & "', " & CDbl(Me.txtGrandTotal.Text) & ", " & CDbl(Me.txtTotalQty.Text) & ",  " & _
        "'" & GCurrentUserName & "', '" & vRemarks & "')"

    intresult = objDA.ExecSP(strSQL, "Trans")

     varOutputRet = CType(objCmd.Parameters(0).Value, Integer)
```

Error is highlighted in the below code in another form when I submit the above code

```
              varOutputRet = CType(objCmd.Parameters(0).Value, Integer)
```

Comment: Hi, What is the value of your parameter in database?

Comment: your first line or last line may look like empty but is null..

Answer (score 0):

Check for `DBNull` before you cast:

```
 varOutputRet = CInt(If(IsDBNull(objCmd.Parameters(0).Value), 0, objCmd.Parameters(0).Value))
```